# How to know if a call has been established? 

Tags: android, telephony, phone-call

Well, I did a program to make a call to any number of my contact list and it works like a charm. The problem is that I would like to know if the connection has been estabilished (the other person has picked up the phone), and I have not any idea about how to do it.

Is there something like an interrupt that can alert me when the connection has been estabilished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

listen to the broadcast ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED, for more information check this out [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html)

Comment: unfortunately this api does not have the ability to detect when a call has been connected.

Comment: ofcourse it does, listen when device state is changed from CALL_STATE_IDLE, to [CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK)

Comment: well I suppose its better than nothing, but its not concrete whether or not the call actually connected or the call was in fact dialing and never got to be active, he would still have the "connected" state if he assumed that this case was true: According to the documentation:
 At least one call exists that is dialing, active, or on hold

Comment: At this point you can take time, and if you are not getting the CALL_STATE_IDLE state again then you can know for sure you are on active call

Comment: Hi I have the same issue. But I dont know how to implement "listen when device state us changed from IDLE TO OFFHOOK? Can you share some code on how you did this?

Comment: Hey Babibu and user1162570 , take a look at my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756815/what-is-the-phonestatelistener-state-when-outgoing-call-is-answered/9756954#9756954 please help! Thanks!