# What is the PhoneStateListener state when outgoing call is answered?

Tags: android, phone-call

I want to know when an outgoing call is answered in my app. I am using a method called `onCallStateChanged()` from the `PhoneStateListener` class. I am looking at the Logcat when the outgoing call is answered to see which state it goes into (IDLE, OFFHOOK or Ringing). As per the documentation I would think it would go into the `OFFHOOK` but that is not the case.
Any ideas on how I can detect the outgoing call being answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phone state is `Phonestate.Offhook` as you are answering the call by offhooking the phone, it's obvious.

Comment: I agree, However when an outgoing call is answered when I  view the log cat it does not move and neither state is called...Any other way I can do this?

Comment: There is no state to distinguish dialing and answered.